# Determinant of Linear Combination of Two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A,B \in M_3 (\mathbb{C})$ such that $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1$. Show that $\det(A + \sqrt{2}\cdot B) \neq 0$

My attempt: Suppose $\det(A + \sqrt{2}\cdot B) = 0$ then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $C = A + \sqrt{2}\cdot B$.

I'm not sure how to use the fact that  $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false. Take$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt2&0&0\\0&-\sqrt{\frac12}&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }B=\operatorname{Id}_3.$$